# R: convert list of numbers to a string

Tags: r, type-conversion, concatenation

This is probably simple in R, but I cannot find a working solution. I have a list of numbers, i.e. c(1,2,3,4) and I want to get one single string "  1  2  3  4" where every number (can be float) have a fixed width.

```
> dput(l)
c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)
> paste(l)
[1] "1"   "1.5" "2"   "2.5"
> paste(as.character(l))
[1] "1"   "1.5" "2"   "2.5"
> str_pad(l,width=7,side="left")
[1] "      1" "    1.5" "      2" "    2.5"
> paste(str_pad(l,width=7,side="left"))
[1] "      1" "    1.5" "      2" "    2.5"
```

And many other tries, nothing work. I need result in the variable not just on the screen.

Comment: You're close - use the `collapse` argument of paste to make the result a single string. `paste(str_pad(l,width=7,side="left"), collapse = "")`